# macosx 10.10 cocoalumberjack linker error

Tags: cocoalumberjack

I use pod to install cocoalumberjack to my macosx project. Here is the output of the error message.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DDLog", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: could you get it to work? what was the problem?